# Could not load file or assembly or one of its dependencies c1flexgrid

Tags: c#, winforms, reference, grapecity

I have problem with my winform project

[image]
I try change the version of c1.Win.c1flexgrid form 2.0 to 2.6 but i cant, How i can fix that problem?
[image]